# How to get access to fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am new to fonts and font-face. I have read a lot of StackOverflow threads about how to get them to work in a website, but, i am confused as to how/where can i download the:

```
.eot
.eot?#iefix
.woff
.ttf
.svg
```

For Gotham Book and Gotham Light? Or fonts in general?

Thanks

Comment: You can generate them. I often use [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webfonts require special licensing.

You can find the Gotham Webfont here:
http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/overview/

There are free alternatives available such as Google Web Fonts (https://www.google.com/fonts/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this link to download particular font  you want

http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/styles/

Download yous font-files and write a code to call a fonts in yous css file as below

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your project there could be different ways you can add specific fonts to a website,
Generally the most common is adding a reference to the header of your site like:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and then you can use the font in the stylesheet adding a property like:

```
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

---

Otherwise you can use [`@font-face`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) rule directly in your stylesheet to import the font and then use it calling the font through the `font-family:` property.

[Here's an article on @font-face I suggest.](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/)